# How do you get hostname of remote computer?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm currently developing a client-server desktop application on C# for my assignment. I managed to retrieve the IP address of remote computer. Can I get the hostname of that remote computer by using IP Address?

Here is my code:

```cs
    private static string GetMachineNameFromIPAddress(string ipAddress)
    {
        string machineName = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(ipAddress);

            machineName = hostEntry.HostName;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }

        return machineName;
    }
```

I put the retrieved IP address into a label

```cs
    var socketip = ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
    ipLabel.Text = socketip;
```

but it's not appearing when I tried to display it with this code

```cs
    string CompName = GetMachineNameFromIPAddress(socketip);
    listBox1.Items.Add("Computer Name: " + CompName);
```

Anyone know why?

Comment: Are you sure the IP address you're getting is for the machine and not the router?

Comment: I doubled checked on remote computer's cmd, it is correct.

Comment: What happens when you call the method? Do you get an incorrect result or is an exception thrown?

Comment: I ran your code and it works fine to return the name.  Can you confirm that the remote server's machine is actually configured in DNS?  Have you tried pinging the server from your local machine by both name and IP?   Do both resolve that way?   My guess is DNS is not configured properly or routing/firewall is preventing.

Comment: What is `client` ?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that DNS may not have a hostname associated with that IP address. If you have access, try running the command below on the client and force the update with DNS. Here's more info on how you would do it: [Renew DNS client registration using the ipconfig command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc780467(v=ws.10))

> ipconfig /registerdns

Alternatively you could use Microsoft's ARP utility and just use the MAC address. Here's an article that would help with that route: [Resolve IP Address And Host Name From MAC Address using C# and Windows ARP Utility](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/11/08/Resolve_IP_Address_And_Host_Name_From_MAC_Address_using_CSharp_and_Windows_ARP_Utility)